# Try / Except all Python errors of a certain type

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

In my Python code, I'm using the PyQt5 module to display a GUI. Sometimes, I encounter a Runtime Error if I delete an element then attempt to use a function on the element's instance. This error is only displayed in the console, and it does not actually interfere with the GUI or terminate it.

Regardless, I would like to remove it (the Runtime Errors). My first thought was to use a `try/except` block on the code, and except the Runtime Error that I was talking about. The problem with this, is that if I encase my whole code with the try/except block, then if the error is caught, it will skip over to the end of my program and terminate:

```py
try:
    # If any errors occur here...
    <code>
except RuntimeError:
    # The GUI will stop entirely, and the Python interpreter will skip to this line
    pass
```

Another solution to my problem is to encase any instance which *could* throw a RuntimeError with a `try/catch` block, like so:

```py
try:
    # If any errors occur here...
    <code that may print an error>
except RuntimeError:
    # Python wont display the error
    pass
```

However given the mass amount of times I would need to do this in my code, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of fixing this problem.

Comment: In general I would say the second case is the better by far. It's generally a bad idea to try-except over large blocks of code - you might miss something bad that's happening that you were not anticipating. With the parts that might raise an error, are they from the same calls or a mix? And are they calls to a library or code you have some more control over? It may be possible to use some kind of decorator pattern or at least a simple function to hide away the try-except blocks, depending on the calls needed.

Comment: Instead of encapsulating each line that might throw an error, you might try to use a function to execute the command that usually throws an error. In this function, you can do the exception handling. From your description it seems as if the error happens in comparable situations. Using functions or methods with good error handling may spare you some trouble.

Comment: Besides the whole error management, if you're getting that kind of error for deleted instance there might be a problem with your code. How are you deleting those instances and why you still try to access them?

Comment: @musicamante I have an event that is called every time a key is pressed, however I also have a shortcut- what happens is that the shortcut deletes (all) the elements, but then the event is called and tries to run one of the element's methods. Surprisingly, this doesn't crash the entire GUI/file, but it does throw the RuntimeError stated in question...

Comment: That might depend on how the "event" is created and what is called afterwards. Despite that, I don't know how you implemented all that, but instead of making things unnecessarily complex, I'd try to find a way to check if the elements actually exist before calling their methods (or a simple flag/attribute that tells that all elements have been cleared). While one of the idioms of python is "it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" this doesn't mean that you should always follow that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I would definitely go with the catch in the specific line calls that might throw the runtime error. This avoids you accidentally suppressing another error you were not anticipating.

Depending on what the calls are that might give the runtime  error, I would prefer a decorator pattern to hide the try-except logic. Something like:

```
from functools import wraps


def catch_runtime_error(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass  # or whatever handle you fancy

    return wrapper
```

which you would then use like:

```
@catch_runtime_error
def the_function_that_raises(...):
    # whatever the body is

the_function_that_raises(...)
```

Alternatively you can use it more directly in your code:

```
def the_function_that_raises(...):
    # whatever the body is

catch_runtime_error(the_function_that_raises)(...)
```

Comment: Smart thinking, I forgot about decorators. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use customs decorators to to this (I don't know your python level but it's not the most beginner friendly thing). For example, this code here do not raise any error:

```
from functools import wraps

def IgnoreError(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper():
        try:
            f()
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
    return wrapper

@IgnoreError
def func1():
    x = 5/0

func1()
```

In your case, you will have to define this function:

```
def IgnoreError(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass
    return wrapper
```

and then anytime you create a function that may raise the RuntimeError, just put the decorator `@IgnoreError` before your definition like this:

```
@IgnoreError
def func():
   <your code here>
```

(if you want [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfCz563ebsU&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kwmIcMDdXSuy_wSqtU-xDP&index=5&t=0s) a video from TechWithTim explaining the decorators)

Comment: I agree with this approach - decorator pattern is one of my favourite patterns! Your answer is good, but you could improve it by adding `wraps` to your decoration. It doesn't matter in most cases, but if you include it it preserves the decorated function's metadata. I.e. function name, docstring, etc.